# Entity Framework 3 context.database.sqlquery causing deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have run into an interesting scenario.  Using the context.database.sqlquery available in the Entity Framework I am calling a stored procedure to update a field.

When calling the procedure directly in management studio no deadlocks occur when editing two or more items.

When calling the same stored procedure using context.database.sqlquery a dealock is encountered, when editing two or more items.

I have found a way to correct for this, but I do not see why calling the procedure from the framework would cause a deadlock.  So I thought I would ask.

```
--Create a temp table to hold items based on userid
CREATE TABLE #tableA
(   
    [Id] int identity (1,1),
    [Item_Id] int
)

INSERT INTO #tableA ([Item_Id]) SELECT [Id] FROM [Items] WHERE [UserId] = @UserId

--All of the other processing is omitted for brevity

--Based on final processing above update the IsActive flag on the Items table
UPDATE i
SET [IsActive] = 0
FROM #tableA ta INNER JOIN [Items] i ON ta.[Item_Id] = i.[Item_Id]
WHERE [IsActive] = 1
```

Again, I have a solution that worked, just trying to understand why a deadlock would occur in EF and not when calling the procedure directly.

BTW, the solution was to add the IsActive bit to the temp table and populating it initially and then on the join in the update statement I used temp table isactive place in the where clause.

```
--Create a temp table to hold items based on userid
CREATE TABLE #tableA
(   
    [Id] int identity (1,1),
    [Item_Id] int,
    [IsActive]
)

INSERT INTO #tableA ([Item_Id], [IsActive]) SELECT [Id], [IsActive] FROM [Items] WHERE [UserId] = @UserId

--All of the other processing is omitted for brevity

--Based on final processing above update the IsActive flag on the Items table
UPDATE i
SET [IsActive] = 0
FROM #tableA ta INNER JOIN [Items] i ON ta.[Item_Id] = i.[Item_Id]
WHERE ta.[IsActive] = 1
```

Comment: Are you using a `TransactionScope` when calling it in your code, by any chance?

Comment: No, I see no indication of TransactionScope being used in the project, but that is something I did read about as a possible option.